# Why is it "'s" after Let and before a verb, example "Let's go" or Let's do something"?

Tags: expressions, contractions

We often learn the structure “Let’s do something”, but why it there an apostrophe-*s* after *let* and before the verb?

Why does we need *’s* in this structure?

Does *’s* means *is* or does it mean *was*?

Comment: It isn't always -'s (us) before a verb, see: *“Let* **me/him/her/them** *do something”*

Comment: A question for English learners.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's a contraction of *let us:*

> Let us go to the store.